# backbone.js collection - Calling fetch repeatedly to get all "pages" from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

When I create a new collection, `fetch` is called automatically once. This gives me the "first page", as well as the URL to the next page + certain number of entries. Now, what I need to do is to populate this collection (all at once, in the beginning) by calling `fetch` repeatedly until the next page field is undefined.

How can I do this? It seems like if I call `fetch` with a callback (success) function, it only calls that ONCE. So something like:

```
fetch(success: function () { 
if (condition)
  fetch again
});
```

It does not call `fetch` repeatedly (until if condition is false). Instead, it calls it once, and since the "fetch again" part was not passed in a success function, it does not have a callback?

How can I get around this? What's the best approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just name the function and pass it into the inner call.

Example (from the view):

```
var self = this;
self.collection.fetch({ success: function success() {
  if (condition) {
    self.collection.fetch({ success: success });
  }
}});
```

**[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/y5DDD/)** is an example.