# backbone.js collections - How to define a success callback for fetch (recursive though)

Tags: javascript, ajax, collections, backbone.js, fetch

So I understand we can do something like this:

Collection.fetch({success: function() { bla.. } } )

But say I wanted something like this:

Collection.fetch( { success: function () { 
if (condition) 
{ **this.fetch()** } }})

The problem is, the second time I call fetch (the one in bold), it won't have the success function associated with it. What I want to do is: Call fetch until that condition becomes true...that condition is based on the data (result) of the previous fetch.

Anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [backbone.js collection - Calling fetch repeatedly to get all "pages" from server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828919/backbone-js-collection-calling-fetch-repeatedly-to-get-all-pages-from-server)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could declare the function outside of the parameter like so, this way you can reference it later.

```
var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
var success = function(){
    if(condition){
        collection.fetch({success : success});
    }
 };
 collection.fetch({success : success});
```